# JSON Auto populate drop down based on value from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm Having an issue with my zip code auto populate. The zip code is entered and the city and state are populated just fine from the AJAX call. My issue is that sometimes certain zip codes have several cities attributed to them. My question is How do I create a drop down for City based on the zip code that is entered?

My code is as follows:

```
$(function() {

    var cache = {};
    var container = $("#validate");
    var errorDiv = container.find("div.text-error");

    /** Handle successful response */
    function handleResp(data)
    {
        // Check for error
        if (data.error_msg)
            errorDiv.text(data.error_msg);
        else if ("City" in data.items[0])
        {
            // Set city and state
            container.find('input[name="City"]').val(data.items[0].City);
            container.find('input[name="State"]').val(data.items[0].StateName);
        }
    }

    // Set up event handlers
    container.find("input[name='zipcode']").on("keyup change", function() {
        // Get zip code
        var zipcode = $(this).val().substring(0, 5);
        if (zipcode.length == 5 && /^[0-9]+$/.test(zipcode))
        {
            // Clear error
            errorDiv.empty();

            // Check cache
            if (zipcode in cache)
            {
                handleResp(cache[zipcode]);
            }
            else
            {
                // Build url
                var url = "http://xxxx.com/ASPFetchers/GetSPROCAsXML.asp?SPROC=EG_GetZipCodeInfo%20/"+(zipcode)+"/&F=JSON";

                // Make AJAX request
                $.ajax({
                    "url": url,
                    "dataType": "json"
                }).done(function(data) {
                    handleResp(data);

                    // Store in cache
                    cache[zipcode] = data;
                }).fail(function(data) {
                    if (data.responseText && (json = $.parseJSON(data.responseText)))
                    {
                        // Store in cache
                        cache[zipcode] = json;

                        // Check for error
                        if (json.error_msg)
                            errorDiv.text(json.error_msg);
                    }
                    else
                        errorDiv.text('Request failed.');
                });
            }
        }
    }).trigger("change");
});
```

My HTML is:

```
    <div id="validate">                                                                             
<label>Zip Code</label>                         
<input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" size =" 5" maxlength = "5" />                            
<div class="text-error"></div>                                                      

<label>City</label>                         
<input type="text" name="City" id="City" />                                                 


<label>State</label>                            
<input type="text" name="State" id="State" disabled="disabled" />                           
<script type="text/javascript" src="../zip/includes/zip2.js"></script>      
</div>
</div>
```

and My JSON response looks like:

```
 items: [{City:FORT%20LAUDERDALE, County:BROWARD, State:FL, StateName:FLORIDA, Latitude:0.4564729,…},…]
0: {City:FORT%20LAUDERDALE, County:BROWARD, State:FL, StateName:FLORIDA, Latitude:0.4564729,…}
1: {City:FT%20LAUDERDALE, County:BROWARD, State:FL, StateName:FLORIDA, Latitude:0.4564729,…}
2: {City:LAZY%20LAKE, County:BROWARD, State:FL, StateName:FLORIDA, Latitude:0.4564729,…}
3: {City:OAKLAND%20PARK, County:BROWARD, State:FL, StateName:FLORIDA, Latitude:0.4564729,…}
4: {City:WILTON%20MANORS, County:BROWARD, State:FL, StateName:FLORIDA, Latitude:0.4564729,…}
```

Thank you very much for your time and knowledge

Comment: This is not a valid JSON string, is that the actual output from PHP?

Comment: I believe it is an Object Array. The form itself is on a .php however the script I am using is Javascript. The zip code function to auto populate the fields works just as it should. You type in the zip, and city and state are captured and place in the field